# twitter api authorization url Parallel connection

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I just finished to build a little app with python (tweepy) using the Twitter API. 
When a user makes a connection to the app, I have to generate a URL in order to get his tokens (access_token and assess_token_secret). The problem is that it can't manage two users at the same time :(

How can I manage this ?

Am I clear enough :D
Thanks in advence

Comment: I'm not familiar with tweepy, but since python is generally object oriented, you can normally just create a second object of the class you use? `api_nr1 = tweepy.API(auth1); api_nr2 = tweepy.API(auth2)`

Comment: The problem is with Twitter :
If I generate a first URL for a first user and at the same time a second user comes, I'll have to generate a second URL. But the first user will get an error from Twitter because of the second user who has generated an other URL.... :D :D